# Elasticsearch aggregation on different search in same query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make a query to aggregate base only on match no matter what other parameters(terms , term , etc...) are used. 
To be more specific I have an online shop where I use multiple filters (color ,size etc..) If I check a field for example color : red the other colors are no longer aggregated.
A solution that I am using is to make 2 separated queries (one for search where filters are applied and other for aggregation. Any idea how can I combine the 2 separated queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-post-filter) which will not apply to your aggregations but will only filter the to-be-returned `hits`. For example:

Create a shop

```
PUT online_shop
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "color": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "size": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Populate it w/ a few products

```
POST online_shop/_doc
{"color":"red","size":35,"name":"Louboutin High heels abc"}

POST online_shop/_doc
{"color":"black","size":34,"name":"Louboutin Boots abc"}

POST online_shop/_doc
{"color":"yellow","size":36,"name":"XYZ abc"}
```

Apply a shared query to the `hits` as well as `aggregations` and use `post_filter` to ... *post-filter* the hits:

```
GET online_shop/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    },
    "by_size": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "size"
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "color": {
              "value": "red"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result

```
{
  ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.11750763,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "online_shop",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "cehma3IBG_KW3EFn1QYa",
        "_score" : 0.11750763,
        "_source" : {
          "color" : "red",
          "size" : 35,
          "name" : "Louboutin High heels abc"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_color" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "black",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "red",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "yellow",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "by_size" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 34,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 35,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 36,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to implement pagination with from and size but only for post_filter?

Comment: `from` & `size` don't affect the aggs, only the already queried `hits`. So not sure what you mean.